# How to get value from struts bean?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts

I am new to struts. I'm just trying to build a simple application that gets the input from the user and display it. For which I got the input from the user and stored it in a bean and I have also displayed it in the next page using bean:write but how to place it in a text box. I tried to use html:text  but I don't know how to place the value in it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Set the property or bean that you want to display in the request attribute and fetch the value from it in the final page:

The syntax for inserting a value in text box is

```
<html:text property="propertyName" value="value"></html:text/>
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I want to get the value from the previous page. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: If I am using request attribute then there is no point in using bean isn't it

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap html:text with html:form. The action attribute of html:form will point to an action defined in struts-config.xml. This action will be associated with a form bean where you have stored the value you are talking about. Then in html:text refer to that property like this

<html:text property="property name where the value is stored"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place that in a text box I think you might want to try  [textfield tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/textfield.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "" to directly get the value of the property from the bean.
Ex:

```
<bean:write name="user" property="username" />
Replace by this:
<html:text name="user" property="username" style="width:150" maxlength="20"/>

In that:
name - is the bean object name
property - is the property of the bean object
```

Good luck!